# How to re-write or modify this code to work the same but without using a break statement

Tags: java, break

How can I get the following code work without using break statement?

I updated and added i = child to bottom of the while loop. I'm also adding these additional comments because someone edited my post and now I can't update it because I need to add more comments. Please don't alter my question. Those comments are there for extra insight. It also hinders my ability to edit my question or update my code.

```
private void percDown(int [] a, int i, int n) {
    numOfCalls++;
    int child = 0;
    int tmp = a[i];

    while(leftChild(i) < n) {
        child = leftChild(i);
        if( child != n - 1 && a[child] < a[child + 1]){
            numOfComparisons++;
            child++;
        }
        if( tmp < a[child]){
            numOfComparisons++;
            a[i] = a[child];
        }
        else
            break;
        i= child;
        a[i] = tmp; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check both the `if` conditions in the `while` condition.

Comment: is it school assignment?

Comment: would that mean creating a new while loop and then combining the conditions of the 2 if statements? Or would that mean putting all of the conditions in the initial while loop?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with sorting, and meaningless to mention "Mark Weiss's percDown() " etc

Answer (score 1):

Just set `n = 0;` instead, or `Integer.MIN_VALUE` if these values can go negative. That will stop your loop. But don't be averse to `break` statements. They are used all the time out here in the real world.

Comment: That's what I initially thought would work, unfortunately, it puts me in an infinite loop  I've nothing against break statements. Just challenging the logic in an effort to further my knowledge of CS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this while condition:

```
while(leftChild(i) < n && (( leftChild(i) != n - 1 && a[leftChild(i)] < a[leftChild(i) + 1]) || tmp < a[leftChild(i)]))
```

Basically I have clubbed both your `if` conditions in the `while` condition. Everything else remains the same.

Comment: How will this give the same result as the OP's original code? The else part only applies to the second if...

Comment: Yes, I'm only needing another way to deal with the second if statement without using a break.

Comment: @Abhi only checking the second if condition in while condition won't solve it. What if the second condition is false, it won't even get into the while loop to check the 1st if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in structure like this:

```
while(A) {
    B;
    if(C){
        D;
    } else {
        break;
    }
    E;
}
```

To tidy it up a bit; it can be written as

```
while(A) {
    B;
    if(C){
        D;
        E;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

To avoid using break, it can be done by:

```
while(A && !C) {
    B;
    if(C){
        D;
        E;
    }
}
```

(You may make up a meaningful boolean flag to represent `C` so that it is more readable instead of putting a long, complex, hard-to-read predicate in while condition.)